Balance consumers with KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter
How does KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter currently handle balancing between multiple instances? I would like that the shards are distributed somewhat evenly when I spin up another instance for scaling.
I found this older ticket https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/99. It seems like there is no rebalancing.
Thanks for your input!

There is no consumer group management in AWS Kinesis and that is not easy to implement from this KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter client. We would need some other independent application to coordinate that behavior. That is already out of spring-integration-aws scope.
Currently it works like: first in - first win. So, indeed might be a situation when all your shards are consumed by a single instance.

Ok, I see. I also found some information here. This section concludes with So, configuring consumer concurrency is important to achieve throughput.
Does this mean that setting a lower concurrency would help other instances acquire locks (e.g. concurrency of 2 means one instance can only hold 2 shards at the same time?)? Or is it still most likely that one instance will end up with all the shards?

The concurrency is for single application instance. It really does not help other instances. One instance still can obtain all the shards for consuming while all other instances will be in idle state.

I’m not sure I understand the javadoc correctly here about concurrency.
My understanding is that while the instance has locks on all the shards at the same time, the record handler that I define in my own code is only called at most concurrency number of times in parallel. Is that how it works?

The point is that one shard is always processed in one thread. So, if you have concurrency 4, but 2 shards, even if there are going to be 4 consumers, only two of them are active - one per shard. If you have more shards, then they are distributed evenly between those consumers: 4 shards, 2 concurrency - 2 shards in each consumer.
